# Database connection in J2ME

Tags: java, mysql, java-me

How to connect with MySQL database using J2ME?

Answer (score 3):

You can't have MySql DB on phone, so at j2me level either you can

- Use [RMS](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/databaserms/) ([Record management system](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wi-rms/))
- Use [webservices](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/allarticles/#ws) to transfer data to server where you can use MySql in backend

Comment: can you send me any tutorial on RMS and i guess in second one we have to connect with servlet

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can do it in Java ME, But in Mobile phone you can not directly connect to MySql or any other external Database. To connect with MySql Database you need to make request to web service for same. That means you need to create one web service which will make database connectivity for you. After Creating this Web Service, you need call this web service from Java ME Code.

for calling web service, please check Jigar Joshi's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897165/how-to-use-web-service-in-j2me-application).
you can also check [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wireless/library/wi-jsr/).