# J2ME database or data management

Tags: java, database, java-me, dictionary, rms

I am using Netbeans IDE (J2ME) for developing a mobile application, a dictionary which retrieve the meaning of the word when user enter a word.

How can I save/retrieve these meanings in the application (in the .jar file) any database? any method? And I have to distribute this application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With java-me you have support of [Record Management System (RMS)](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/databaserms/), You could store little data there,

The nice way would be store little information and when user queries the word see if it is there in local RMS , provide it, Otherwise you [make a webservice call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897165/how-to-use-web-service-in-j2me-application) to your server and provide the information to user

Comment: can i transfer RMS alone/inside with the .jar file ?

Comment: No, you need to fill it programatically

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is a key/value data structure, just like a Hashtable. You can store your data on jar file as a Java properties file (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html).

As Java ME does not have the java.util.Properties class you have to do the loading manually.

```
    public class Properties extends Hashtable {

        public Properties(InputStream in) throws IOException {
            if (in == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("in == null");
            }

            StringBuffer line = new StringBuffer();

            while (readLine(in, line)) {
                String s = line.toString().trim();

                if (s.startsWith("#") == false) {
                    int i = s.indexOf('=');

                    if (i > 0) {
                        String key = s.substring(0, i).trim();
                        String value = s.substring(i + 1).trim();

                        put(key, value);
                    }
                }
                line.setLength(0);
            }
        }

        private boolean readLine(InputStream in, StringBuffer line) throws IOException {
            int c = in.read();

            while (c != -1 && c != '\n') {
                line.append((char)c);
                c = in.read();
            }

            return c >= 0 || line.length() > 0;
        }

        public String get(String key) {
            return (String) super.get(key);
        }
    }
```

Here is a sample

```
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/dictionary.properties");
    Properties dictionary = new Properties(is);
```